# How to execute a bulk ElasticSearch operation from an AppSync resolver?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-appsync, resolver, vtl

I'm trying to execute a bulk operation over an ElasticSearch index from a VTL AppSync resolver.

Specifically this mutation:

```
input CreateTopicsInput {
  language: String!
  texts: [String!]!
}

type Mutation {
  createTopics(input: CreateTopicsInput!): [Topic!]
}
```

And I created the following resolver:
Mutation.createTopics.req.vtl

```
#set( $body = "" )
#set( $q = '"' )
#foreach( $text in $ctx.args.input.texts )
  #set( $body = $body.concat("{ ${q}index${q}: { ${q}_id${q}: ${q}${text}${q} } }
") )
  #set( $body = $body.concat("{ ${q}text${q}: ${q}$text${q}, ${q}suggest${q}: { ${q}input${q}: ${q}$text${q} } }
") )
#end
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "POST",
  "path": "/topic-${ctx.args.input.language}/doc/_bulk",
  "params": {
    "headers" : [ { "Content-Type" : "application/x-ndjson" } ],
    "body": "$body"
  }
}
```

And when executed for example with this data:

```
mutation CreateTopic {
  createTopics(input: {
    language: "en",
    texts: [ "COVID", "Election" ]}) {
    text
  }
}
```

Seems to output a correct invocation:

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "POST",
  "path": "/topic-en/doc/_bulk",
  "params": {
    "headers" : [ { "Content-Type" : "application/x-ndjson" } ],
    "body": "{ "index": { "_id": "COVID" }
{ "text": "COVID" }
{ "index": { "_id": "Election" }
{ "text": "Election" }
"
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Specifically it throws:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createTopics": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createTopics"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (String)\"{\n  \"version\": \"2017-02-28\",\n  \"operation\": \"POST\",\n  \"path\": \"/topic-en/doc/_bulk\",\n  \"params\": {\n    \"headers\" : { \"Content-Type\" : \"application/x-ndjson\" },\n    \"body\": \"{ \"index\": { \"_id\": \"CODID\" } }\n{ \"text\": \"CODID\", \"suggest\": { \"input\": \"CODID\" } }\n{ \"index\": { \"_id\": \"Election\" } }\n{ \"text\": \"Election\", \"suggest\": { \"input\": \"Election\" } }\n\"\n  }\n}\n\"; line: 7, column: 18]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

i played a little bit around and figure out that you would need to

- quote your double quotes
- write all in one line, divided by a "\n"
- the last part in that line needs to be an "\n" again

As example:

```
{
 "version": "2018-05-29",
 "method": "POST",
 "resourcePath": "/_msearch/template",
 "params": {
   "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "application/x-ndjson"
   },
   "body": "{ \"index\": { \"_id": \"COVID\" }\n{ \"text\": \"COVID\" }\n"
 }
}
```

Of course, this is not very convinced and for your use case this could work better:

```
#set($ndjson = [])
$util.qr($ndjson.add({ "index": "COVID" }))
$util.qr($ndjson.add({ "text": "COVID", "Param2": "vaccine" } }))
 
 
{
 "version": "2018-05-29",
 "method": "POST",
 "resourcePath": "/_msearch/template",
 "params": {
   "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "application/x-ndjson"
   },
   "body": "#foreach ($line in $ndjson)$util.escapeJavaScript($util.toJson($line))\n#end"
 }
}
```

The (maybe) problematic part could be the JavaScript Escaping. Not sure how your data looks like but it could result into some more quoted data as needed.

P.s: i switched my implementation to the last mentioned example and it works fine for the multi search.

Comment: I am getting 'Unable to transform for the body: $[params][body].' with your approach ..

Answer (score 0):

there's also a solution for js-runtime resolver.

```js
import { util } from "@aws-appsync/utils";

export function request(ctx) {
  const bulkBody =
    ctx.args.logs
      .map((log) => {
        const metadata = {
          index: "INDEX_NAME",
        };

        return `${JSON.stringify(metadata)}\n${JSON.stringify(log)}`;
      })
      .join("\n") + "\n";

  return {
    operation: "POST",
    path: "/_bulk",
    params: {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-ndjson",
      },
      body: { bulkBody },
    },
  };
}

export function response(ctx) {
  if (ctx.error) {
    util.error(ctx.error.message, ctx.error.type);
  }
  return ctx.result;
}
```